# Extracting member types from a parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, containers, variadic-templates, variadic

I would like to define a function that takes an arbitrary number of containers and that number minus one arguments with respective value_types of all but the last container.

I can easily extract the value_type of the last container and use it as a return type, however, I am clueless with respect to defining the types for the arguments. I would imagine that a folding an std::integer_sequence inside std::tuple_element_t might be a way to do this but I failed to make it work.

```
// example: 1D interpolator
template<typename... ContainerTypes>
typename std::tuple_element_t<
    sizeof...(ContainerTypes) - 1,
    std::tuple<ContainerTypes...>>::value_type
interpolate(const ContainerTypes& ... /*, ??? */)
{
    // (...)
    return {};
}

// intended use
std::array<int, 2> x{0, 2};
std::array<double, 2> y{0, 2};
int x_query{1};

double y_interpolated{interpolate(x, y)}; // compiles
//double y_interpolated{interpolate(x, y, x_query)}; // this is what I want
```

Comment: i dont really get the last part "...and the same number minus one of the arguments of the respective value_types of the containers", what instantiation do you want to get for the call `interpolate(x, y, 0.5)` ? Container types is obvious, but how do you infer in that case the type of the last parameter from the container types?

Comment: @François Andrieux Good point. Edited.

Comment: ...`double` because common type of `int` and `double` is `double` ?

Comment: @user463035818 No because double is the value_type of the last container passed in, i.e. typename decltype(y)::value_type.

Comment: variadic template should be the last argument to allow deduction.

Comment: ah ok, so it is always the first container plus arbitrary number of containers and a value of that container type, right?

Comment: You can use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to get the type that a set of types can all implicitly convert to, if such a type exists, instead of relying on the last type being the correct one.

Comment: @user463035818 I've tried to make it clear in the example of a 1D interpolator: in this case I would like to take in two containers (x values and y values) and an x value (matching the value_type of the x container) and return an interpolated y value (matching the value_type of the y container). Although I could make overloads for 1D, 2D and 3D, I was thinking of a generic way to define this.

Comment: Can't you split your function instead ? something like `interpolator{x_container, y_contianer, z_conainter}(x_value, y_value)`.

Comment: concerning variadic vs overloads, maybe consider that not only you have difficulties when writing the variadic, but also overloads are easier to use for the caller

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. If you're suggesting to define a class with an operator(), then the problem is equivalent - how to define the types of its arguments? If, on the other hand, you mean defining overloads then for sure I can certainly define as many overloads as any user may potentially need. I was just curious whether there is a generic way to do this in one go.

Comment: @user463035818 In what way? In the case shown in the example the caller would not be able to tell whether it was an overload written by hand or generated from the template.

Comment: Writing some overloads in the question would make the question clearer I think.

Comment: and grouping your arguments by type might make the interface simpler: `template <typename Ret, typename ... InputContainers, typename TargetContainer, typename ... InputValues> Ret interpolate(const std::tuple<InputContainers...>&, const TargetContainer&, const std::tuple<InputValues...>&);` and then expose constraints on the type: (`Ret = TargetContainer::value_type` so Ret can be removed and replaced, same for `InputValues`).

Comment: "the same number minus one of the arguments of the respective value_types of the containers." -- if you have minus one, *they are no longer respective*.  The respective value types of all but the last container is I think what you want.

Comment: "In what way?" with an overload I can look at the signature and every single parameter is explicitly listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to transform overloads:

```
template <typename C1, typename CLast>
typename CLast::value_type interpolate(const C1&,
                                       const CLast&,
                                       typename C1::value_type);

template <typename C1, typename C2, typename CLast>
typename CLast::value_type interpolate(const C1&, const C2&,
                                       const CLast&
                                       typename C1::value_type, typename C2::value_type);
// ...
```

into variadic template.

It would be easier to have intermediate structure:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct InterpolatorImpl
{
    const T& t;
    std::tuple<const Ts&...> ts;

    InterpolatorImpl(const T& t, const Ts&... ts) : t(t), ts(ts...) {}

    typename T::value_type operator()(typename Ts::value_type...) const {/*...*/};
};


template <std::size_t...Is, typename Tuple>
auto InterpolatorHelper(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const Tuple& tuple) {
    using LastType = tuple_element_t<sizeof...(Is), tuple>;
    return InterpolatorImpl<LastType,
                            std::decay_t<std::tuple_element_t<Is, tuple>>...>
        {
            std::get<sizeof...(Is)>(tuple),
            std::get<Is>(tuple)...
        };
}

template <typename ...Ts>
auto Interpolator(const Ts&... ts) {
    return InterpolatorHelper(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>(),
                              std::tie(ts...));
}
```

And then, call it:

```
std::array<int, 2> x{0, 2};
std::array<double, 2> y{0, 2};
int x_query{1};

double y_interpolated{Interpolator(x, y)(x_query)};
```

Or change your signature to

```
template <typename ... InputContainers, typename TargetContainer>
typename TargetContainer::value_type
interpolate(const std::tuple<InputContainers...>&,
            const TargetContainer&,
            const std::tuple<typename InputContainers::value_type...>&);
```

Comment: Makes sense. I knew that I had to use index_sequence for the job somehow... Thank you!